# Why do all my views move to the lower left corner when printing?

Tags: cocoa, printing, nsview

I have an AppKit/Cocoa app that isn't document based (just NSViews/NSWindows).  I'm trying to print the contents of the current window.  There's currently no print-specific code in my application.

[image: What I'm seeing]

My content is rendering OK in the window, but when I go to print it, everything is suddenly moved to the lower-lefthand corner, including several NSTextFields.

Why is this happening?  And what should I do to get a layout that matches the one in my window?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the issue is related to using layer-backed views.  When I convert my views to be non-layer-backed, they print in the expected orientation.

I'm guessing this either isn't supported or is a bug, but it's not clear to me which is the case here.